# How to get a popup box to appear when you click on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, popup

I´m trying to make a popup box appear when I click on a div box. I´m haven´t done a lot of js or jquery, so I have a hard time figuring out how to do it. I got a box `(class="box")` that take up most of the screen and then a couple of boxes inside the first box. So when the second box is clicked `(class="profile1")` I want an popup box to appear.I later going to insert a picture were it sayes `class="picture"`, would be nice if that was clickable as well

```
<div class="box"> 

    <div class="profile1"> 
        <div class="picture"></div>
        <p class="name">NAME</p>
    </div>

</div>
```

**css**

```
.box {
left: 19.5%;
top: 11.5%;
height:85%;
right:2.2%;
background-color: #F2F2F2;
border-radius: 5px;
position: absolute;
border: 1px soid F2F2F2(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
z-index:-1;
overflow: auto;
}

.profile1 {
margin-left:1.7%;
margin-top:6%;
height:40%;
width:18%;
background-color:#0D7BFF;
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
border-radius:2px;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to do it?
Appreciate all help

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :)

Comment: Thank you, I understand now, writing an answer ;)

Comment: Try to checkout [**Jqueryui dialog**](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery UI like this:

JS:

```
$(function(){
        $('.profile1').on("click", function(e){
            e.preventDefault()
            $('.picture').dialog({
            width: 600,
            height: 'auto',
            modal:true,
            title: 'Picture',
            overlay: { backgroundColor: "#000", opacity: 0.9 }
            })
        })
       })
```

HTML:

```
<div class="box"> 
 <div class="box"> <div class="profile1"> 
  <p class="name">NAME</p>
 </div>
 <div class="picture">Photo Here...</div>

</div>
```

CSS for ".picture":

```
.picture{
    display:none;
    width:30%;
    height:30%;
}
```

And don't forget to include jQuery UI in addition to jQuery and the jQuery UI CSS:

jQuery: `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>`

jQuery UI:`<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>`

CSS: `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.min.css`(you should download this CSS, not link to CDN)

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/91k8xa22/

Answer (score 0):

Tell me if I can improve it :)

https://jsfiddle.net/www139/x6q7Ls5g/

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var profileBox = document.getElementsByClassName('profile1')[0];
  var picture = document.getElementsByClassName('picture')[0];
  profileBox.addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementById('popupbox').style.display = 'block';
    picture.innerHTML = '<img src="http://freetopwallpaper.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/beautiful-background-wallpaper-hd-3.jpg">';
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  left: 19.5%;
  top: 11.5%;
  height: 85%;
  right: 2.2%;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  border: 1px soid F2F2F2(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: auto;
}
.profile1 {
  margin-left: 1.7%;
  margin-top: 6%;
  height: 40%;
  width: 18%;
  background-color: #0D7BFF;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
#popupbox {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  background-color: #eee;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="profile1">
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <p class="name">NAME</p>
  </div>
</div>
<!--popup box-->
<div id="popupbox">This is the popup box</div>
<!--end popup box-->
```

Answer (score 0):

```
here is new one,

html :

<div class="box"> 
  <div class="profile1"> 
    <div class="picture"></div>
    <p class="name">NAME</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="popup">popup</div>

css :

.box {
   left: 19.5%;
   top: 11.5%;
   height:85%;
   right:2.2%;
   background-color: #F2F2F2;
   border-radius: 5px;
   position: absolute;
   border: 1px soid F2F2F2(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
   z-index:-1;
   overflow: auto;
  }

.profile1 {
  margin-left:1.7%;
  margin-top:6%;
  height:40%;
  width:18%;
  background-color:#0D7BFF;
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  border-radius:2px;
}

.popup
 {
 display: none;
 width: 40%;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: 50px;
 background: #eee;
 border-radius: 8px;
 box-shadow: 0 0 10px #999;
 }

 #close
   { 
    float: right;
   }

js :

$(".profile1").click(function(){
  $(".popup").show();
})
$("#close").click(function(){
 $(".popup").hide();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/erasad22/vjpsrtux/